# Duplicate questions that may result in different answers since the original was asked

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, time

There is a question I want to ask on stackoverflow regarding views on free web development ide's. The question is inherently subjective and it is also a duplicate, in a sense.

However, the question *has* been asked [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181710/what-is-the-best-free-web-development-ide) before and most are closed as duplicates to a question asked in [Sept. 08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140707/web-development-ide-suggestions) (from what I have been able to find). Stackoverflow also, in my opinion, has the right target audience to ask that question. But a lot changes in 2 years, such tools advance or are left behind in the wake of better products. I expect responses to the same question could be different now.

So what are the views on questions of this nature? Should it be asked on stackoverflow and if so how can I avoid it being immediately flamed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about adding a bounty to the older question to get it some current attention and possibly some new answers if new options exist now.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the consensus in [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions) too.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question and #jzd has a valid answer. But what about new users. I feel the barrier to entry for new users can be unnecessary high. Especially since there are so many established technologies, with many many experts. For instance on stackoverflow I would not be able to comment on a question like this. I agree, sometimes there might just be fresh way of approaching old problems.

Comment: But here on Meta you *can* comment with just 1 rep, so: how is this an answer?

Comment: I am specifically commenting on the stackoverflow site

Comment: I meant: how is *your* above post answering this very question? Shouldn't it be a comment to jzd's answer?

Answer (score 1):

A question about on 'views on free web development ide's' is very likely to be closed as 'not constructive'.